# Qt 4.8.2 + vs2010 + static + project build issues LNK2019 & LNK2005

Tags: visual-c++, qt4, linker-errors, static-linking

I had successfully compiled a static version of qt4.8.2 by following the instructions from this post http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/02/01/how-to-compile-qt-4-7-with-visual-studio-2010/

However, I encountered a list of errors when compile my project, they are LNK2019 & LNK2005 related.

I attached the error messages at the bottom.

For the LNK2005 related errors , I included LIBCMT at Linker->Input->Ignore Specific Default Libraries, and its related errors disappear from the error list, but is that the right way to do it?

For the LNK2019 related errors, I couldn't resolve them, please give me some instructions.

Here is my project settings:

```
C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library: Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)

C/C++ -> Language -> Treat WChar_t As Built in Type: No ( /Zc:wchar_t- )

Linker-> Input -> Additional Dependencies:

Imm32.lib
Ws2_32.lib
winmm.lib
qtmaind.lib
QtCored.lib
QtGuid.lib
wsock32.lib
```

LNK2019 related error messages:

```
- Error 161 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
   "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct
   std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall
   QString::toStdString(void)const "
   (__imp_?toStdString@QString@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
   referenced in function "private: void __thiscall
   MainForm::on_actionConfiguration_triggered(void)"
   (?on_actionConfiguration_triggered@MainForm@@AAEXXZ) C:\Working\ProjLocation\test\mainform.obj   test

 - Error    163 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
   "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QString & __thiscall
   QString::append(char const *)" (__imp_?append@QString@@QAEAAV1@PBD@Z)
   referenced in function "private: void __thiscall
   MainForm::summaries_series(struct series const *)"
   (?summaries_series@MainForm@@AAEXPBUseries@@@Z)  C:\Working\ProjLocation\test\mainform.obj   test

 -  Error   162 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
   "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QString::QString(char const
   *)" (__imp_??0QString@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall MainForm::on_actionLogin_triggered(void)"
   (?on_actionLogin_triggered@MainForm@@AAEXXZ) C:\Working\ProjLocation\test\mainform.obj   test
```

LNK2005 related error messages:

```
- Error 12 error LNK2005: __set_invalid_parameter_handler already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj) C:\Working\ProjLocation\test\LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) test

<more LIBCMT & LIBCMTD related errors…..>

- Error 17 error LNK2005: “void __cdecl _invalid_parameter(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)” (?_invalid_parameter@@YAXPBG00II@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj) C:\Working\ProjLocation\test\LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Qt project's properties created by the vs add-in was changed, after I re-compiled the Qt source.